# The method 'forEach' isn't defined for the type 'Object'

Tags: flutter, dart, foreach

i made a video player app I saw an example from this YouTube video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gU1OLKBcys&t=739s

but i face this problem

**The method 'forEach' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'forEach'.**

[image]

How can I fix it? or is there any way to help me?

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    linkRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('links').doc('urls');
    super.initState();
    getData();
    print(videoID);
  }

  _addItemFuntion() async {
    await linkRef.set({
      _addItemController.text.toString(): _addItemController.text.toString()
    }, SetOptions(merge: true));
    Flushbar(
        title: 'Added',
        message: 'updating...',
        duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
        icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline))
      ..show(context);
    setState(() {
      videoID.add(_addItemController.text);
    });
    print('added');
    FocusScope.of(this.context).unfocus();
    _addItemController.clear();
  }

  getData() async {
    await linkRef
        .get()
        .then((value) => value.data()?.forEach((key, value) {
        if (!videoID.contains(value)) {
        videoID.add(value);
        }
        }))
        .whenComplete(() => setState(() {
              videoID.shuffle();
              showItem = true;
            }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried casting specific type: (value.data()? as Map<X, Y>).forEach...

Comment: Have you tried adding .toList() before forEach()

Comment: Thanks for the comments,Do you have an example or a guide ?
I've tried fixing it but it doesn't work. i'm  beginner

Answer (score 0):

Because you are receiving a single document, the data always would be a map,
you have to cast it first if your data is ok, for example:

```dart
then((value){
   /// if the data is a list;
   (value.data as List).forEach();
   /// if the data is a map as it should be
   (value.data['myList'] as List).forEach();
});
```

Comment: When I map a data in part 
`if (!videoID.contains(value)) {
        videoID.add(value);
  }` is Undefined